# Google Places Api, Place auto-complete mBound Query

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api, bounds

I am new to Google Place API, and I am going through [Google reference Guide of place auto-complete](https://developers.google.com/places/android/autocomplete)

To get prediction for auto complete addresses or places there is a parameter which **bounds the map** for prediction.

```
PendingResult result =
    Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, query,
        mBounds, mAutocompleteFilter);
```

I want to know what the most efficient way to **do not bound** the map so I can run prediction for any part of the world.

For example If I enter Sydney Australia I get predictions from Sydney and If I enter Paris France I get predictions from there!

Comment: @DanielNugent I don't want to create bounds dynamically based on the current location. My app requirement is to get places locations from all around the world, like I explained in question.

Comment: I thought you meant the device entering  the area.  In the case that you want the user to select the area through input, you can have a separate input for the user to enter the area to search, and generate the bounds based on the area selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in a bounds for the entire world, i.e. a LatLngBounds from (-90, -180) to (90, 180).

Alternatively: just pass in a bounds around the devices location—because the bounds here is just a **bias** and not a **limit**.  As https://developers.google.com/places/android/autocomplete says [emphasis mine]:

> A `LatLngBounds` object, **biasing** the results to a specific area specified by latitude and longitude bounds.

So a bounds for Sydney, Australia will still allow the user to autocomplete "Paris, France" just fine!